# vba if elseif else-statement doesn't give output i want it to be

Tags: excel, vba

In VBA, I'm using an if, elseif, else-statement, but it doesn't give the output I actually want it to be.

```
Sub oefening1()
Dim jaarinkomen As Long
jaarinkomen = InputBox("Wat is uw jaarinkomen?")
If jaarinkomen < 18300 Then
    MsgBox ("U zit in klasse minimumloon of lager")
ElseIf 18300 <= jaarinkomen < 36500 Then
    MsgBox ("U zit in klasse benedenmodaal")
ElseIf 36500 <= jaarinkomen < 73000 Then
    MsgBox ("U zit in klasse bovenmodaal")
ElseIf 73000 <= jaarinkomen < 1000000 Then
    MsgBox ("U zit in klasse boven dubbelmodaal")
Else
    MsgBox ("U zit in klasse miljonair")
End If
End Sub
```

The problem is that whatever number i type in that is greater than 18300, it always gives the first elseif msgbox as output. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: When dealing with numbers, always go from max to min.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code could be repaired with proper syntax and the use of the And operator but a Select Case seems better suited.

```
Sub oefening1()

    Dim jaarinkomen As Long

    jaarinkomen = InputBox("Wat is uw jaarinkomen?")

    Select Case jaarinkomen 
      Case is < 18300
        MsgBox ("U zit in klasse minimumloon of lager")
      Case is < 36500
        MsgBox ("U zit in klasse benedenmodaal")
      Case is < 73000 
        MsgBox ("U zit in klasse bovenmodaal")
      Case is < 1000000 
        MsgBox ("U zit in klasse boven dubbelmodaal")
      Case Else 
        MsgBox ("U zit in klasse miljonair")
    End Select

End Sub
```

Regardless of whether you use a Select Case or If ElseIf End If, there is no reason to keep checking conditions that have been passed over. If jaarinkomen is not less than 18300 in the first condition, you don't have to check if it is greater than 18300 in the second condition.

Comment: Your way will always stop on the first Case or the Case Else, because or all the numbers will be greater than 18300 or lesser.

Comment: I'm afraid that is incorrect Damian. Unlike some other programming languages (particularly those C based) VBA's Select Case'short circuits' and doesn't process past the first matching Case. Try it and see.

Comment: Sorry, you are right I was thinking like if it's greater than, and it's checking if it's lesser than... Just like mine but the other way!

Comment: @a1a1a1a1a1, while your [edit] is more syntactically correct the VBE will insert those `is` operators automatically if they are omitted.

Answer (score 0):

Since it will stop on the first `If` or `Case` you should go from max to min:

```
Option Explicit
Sub oefening1()

    Dim jaarinkomen As Long
    jaarinkomen = InputBox("Wat is uw jaarinkomen?")

    Select Case jaarinkomen
        Case Is >= 73000, Is < 1000000
            MsgBox ("U zit in klasse miljonair")
        Case Is >= 36500
            MsgBox ("U zit in klasse boven dubbelmodaal")
        Case Is >= 18300
            MsgBox ("U zit in klasse benedenmodaal")
        Case Is < 18300
            MsgBox ("U zit in klasse minimumloon of lager")
        Case Else
            MsgBox ("U zit in klasse miljonair")
    End Select

End Sub
```

This way you don't need to use > And < and it's easier.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can test *between* in that way. If you break out the between into two parts, it seems to work:

```
Sub oefening1()
Dim jaarinkomen As Long
jaarinkomen = InputBox("Wat is uw jaarinkomen?")
If jaarinkomen < 18300 Then
    MsgBox ("U zit in klasse minimumloon of lager")
ElseIf 18300 <= jaarinkomen And jaarinkomen < 36500 Then
    MsgBox ("U zit in klasse benedenmodaal")
ElseIf 36500 <= jaarinkomen And jaarinkomen < 73000 Then
    MsgBox ("U zit in klasse bovenmodaal")
ElseIf 73000 <= jaarinkomen And jaarinkomen < 1000000 Then
    MsgBox ("U zit in klasse boven dubbelmodaal")
Else
    MsgBox ("U zit in klasse miljonair")
End If
End Sub
```

---

Further to this, a much simpler and more scalable way to achieve this would be simply:

```
jaarinkomen = InputBox("Wat is uw jaarinkomen?")

salaries = Array(0, 18300, 36500, 73000, 1000000, 9900000)
responses = Array("U zit in klasse minimumloon of lager", "U zit in klasse benedenmodaal", "U zit in klasse bovenmodaal", "U zit in klasse boven dubbelmodaal", "U zit in klasse miljonair")

MsgBox responses(Application.Match(jaarinkomen - 0.01, salaries, True) - 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

This will **fix** and **simplify** your code, because you don't actually need the **lower bound** condition on each `ElseIf`:

```
Sub oefening1()
    Dim jaarinkomen As Long
    jaarinkomen = InputBox("Wat is uw jaarinkomen?")
    If jaarinkomen < 18300 Then
        MsgBox ("U zit in klasse minimumloon of lager")
    ElseIf jaarinkomen < 36500 Then
        MsgBox ("U zit in klasse benedenmodaal")
    ElseIf jaarinkomen < 73000 Then
        MsgBox ("U zit in klasse bovenmodaal")
    ElseIf jaarinkomen < 1000000 Then
        MsgBox ("U zit in klasse boven dubbelmodaal")
    Else
        MsgBox ("U zit in klasse miljonair")
    End If
End Sub
```